# Read Resource File in application which has been uploaded to Azure Batch

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I am using Azure batch Service and I am able to add applications,pools and tasks to the same .I have attached a resource file to each task.I am confused about how to access the resource file  or inputs provided to the task in the application that I have uploaded to the Azure batch .Please help me in the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have attached the ResourceFile(s) to the individual tasks then the file(s) should be uploaded to the filePath you specified(if any) appended to the environment variable in your task of `AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-compute-node-environment-variables).

For an ad-hoc experience you can download https://azure.github.io/BatchExplorer/ and navigate to an existing node and/or task to see a file explorer for how the directories in the node are layed out.

Comment: Hi brklein ,.I need to do proccesing on the uploaded resource file using the application. Say I have uploaded an console application  to applications in Azure Batch and the application needs to read the Resource file to process .May I know in the console application ,by using this command "AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR " can we retrieve the file and do further processing.